# Minimum height on vertically expandable div

Tags: css, html, height

Is there a way to set a minimum height for a div, but still allow it to be expandable?

For example, I want a div to have an exact height of 300px when my page loads.  However, if more content is added to the div with javascript, I want it to expand after that.

If I specify a height and the content expands past the div, it either clips or adds scrollbars, depending on the value of overflow.

If I don't specify a height, it only expands as far as the content.

Thanks

Here's the solution I used to fix this on ie6, courtesy of [Dustin Diaz](http://www.dustindiaz.com/min-height-fast-hack/)

```
selector { 
  min-height: 300px;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS property `min-height` does exactly this. Note that it does not work properly in IE6, however IE6 treats the `height` property as `min-height`, so you can use [IE conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to set a `height` property in a style sheet that is only loaded by IE6.

Comment: and don't forget that there's no such thing as min-height for the, you know, Microsoft's internet browsing utility 6.0. Specify _height for that.